# firestore Data Query in limited amount

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I have a collection in firestore and it read data all its at once is there any way that we can read 10 data at a time and show to user and when user want to see next 10 we can show them . this will reduce my read in firestore and make app smooth  , is there is any way to achive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination in Firestore works based on cursors, instead of on offsets. But if you keep that in mind, yes it is possible to show the data in pages. See the Firestore documentation on [paginating data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), and FlutterFire documentation on [querying](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying) in general.

Comment: can you give a example how to implement in flutter . I would be very helpful to me

Comment: The API works the same across all platforms, so have a look at the links in my answer - and https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html. If you're still struggling after that, post a new question with what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a look at the documentation, you quickly find

`citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population").limit(2);`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data